# How to add a countdown to woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Im trying to add a javascript countdown to the products in the product catalog (woocommerce shop page).

I have added this code to the wordpress functions.php in my child theme, but it only seem to wants to work for one product.

The countdown works but it is just not adding to the others products. would i need to add the Javascript in a foreach? But not in the functions, rather in a separate JS file??

Thanks Guys

````
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'lottery_data');

function lottery_data() {
  global $product;

  $min_tickets                = $product->get_min_tickets();
  $max_tickets                = $product->get_max_tickets();
  $lottery_participants_count = !empty($product->get_lottery_participants_count()) ? $product->get_lottery_participants_count() : '0';
  $lottery_dates_to           = $product->get_lottery_dates_to();
  $lottery_dates_from         = $product->get_lottery_dates_from();
  $lottery_num_winners        = $product->get_lottery_num_winners();

  $diff = strtotime($lottery_dates_to) - strtotime($lottery_dates_from);
  $now = time();
  $your_date = strtotime($lottery_dates_from);
  $datediff = $now - $your_date;
  $ticketsLeft = $max_tickets - $lottery_participants_count;

  echo '
    <script>
      const second = 1000,
      minute = second * 60,
      hour = minute * 60,
      day = hour * 24;

      let countDown = new Date("'.$lottery_dates_to.'").getTime(),
      x = setInterval(function() {

        let now = new Date().getTime(),
        distance = countDown - now;

        document.querySelector(".days").innerText = Math.floor(distance / (day)),
        document.querySelector(".hours").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (day)) / (hour)),
        document.querySelector(".minutes").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (hour)) / (minute)),
        document.querySelector(".seconds").innerText = Math.floor((distance % (minute)) / second);

      }, second);
    </script>


  <hr class="blueLine">
  <div class="customify-grid">
  <div id="countdown" class="customify-col-4_md-4_sm-6_xs-12 center">
    <div class="countdown-container" style="font-size:13px;">
      <span class="days"></span> : <span class="hours"></span> : <span class="minutes"></span> : <span class="seconds"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="customify-col-4_md-4_sm-6_xs-12 center">
  '. $ticketsLeft .'
  </div>
  <div class="customify-col-4_md-4_sm-6_xs-12 center">
  '.$lottery_dates_to.'
  </div>
  </div>';
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you have different files one for each production you should add the javascript code in a diferent file and just include it on each product file.

Just wrap up the javascript on a <php echo ?> file and use the include("file path").
You should not need the each if they are on diferent files.

If the case is to have all products back-end on one file then yes you will need the each.

You can do this by checking the length on the HTML objects with that class name and then place the loop by ID.

Thats how i would do it.

Comment: Thanks, yeah it is template based. In this instance its the woocommerce Shop page